# Android emulator browser detecting

Tags: android, browser, android-emulator

I'm developing a mobile version of a website. I'm currently using this Javascript to detect and redirect the user:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
                (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) ||
                (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
        { 
        window.location = "http://sitename.com/m/";
    }
```

Works fine with iPhone and iPod, but no success with Android. I'm using the Android Emulator within Eclipse. I don't have an Android gadget to actually test it.

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use **location.replace** instead of **window.location**
Example:

```
if( (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ) { 
    location.replace("http://sitename.com/m/");
}
```

I used this code and it works on iphone/itouch and android phones/devices.

Comment: This helped me out too. Just to be clear, it appears that windows.location is not supported on Android. location.replace() works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is mine JavaScript function to detect Android device:

```
function isAndroid() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    return ua.match(/Android/) 
        || ua.match(/Dalvik/)
        || ua.match(/GINGERBREAD/)
        || ua.match(/Linux;.*Mobile Safari/)
        || ua.match(/Linux 1\..*AppleWebKit/)
};
```